# How to handle reading non-existing file in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Am trying to read some files from HDFS using spark `sc.wholeTextFiles`, I pass a list of the required files, yet the job keeps throwing

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.showString.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:
```

if one of the files didn't exist.

how can I bypass the not found files and only read found ones ?

Comment: use exception handling - Try, Except

Comment: try except will be on the whole function right ?, or will be on file level ?

Comment: both should work

Comment: @AliYesilli, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jvm File system from spark context to check file

```
fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("path/to/file.csv"))
```

```
fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("test.csv"))
True

fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("fail_test.csv"))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

To know if a file exists (and delete it, in my case) I do the following:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
if (fs.exists(new Path(fullPath))) {
  println("Output directory already exists. Deleting it...")
  fs.delete(new Path(fullPath), true)
}
```

Comment: I think to check file by file, in my case will consume sometime, I might do that if there no other solution though